# Convert mongodb connection string to PHP

Tags: laravel, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I have the following connection string generated from MongoDB:

```
mongodb+srv://admin:<password>@cluster0-n74zb.mongodb.net/test
```

I want to place the connection data in Laravel,
 Here is what I have tried but it doesn't connect.

```
  'mongodb' => array(
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => 'cluster0-n74zb.mongodb.net/test',
            'port'     => 27017,
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'xxxxxx',
            'database' => 'driving',
            'options' => array(
                'db' => 'admin' // sets the authentication database required by mongo 3
            )
        ),
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @Oleg: Updated the question.

Comment: At a minimum you need to provide the complete error message.